# Unable to save <file location> in Sublime after adding "atomic_save": false

Tags: javascript, sublimetext

When I  try to save files, a pop up shows up which says Unable to save. according to some answers I found regarding this, I tried 
adding "atomic_save": false in preferences.sublime-settings.But it doesn't seems to be working
my current preference.sublime-settings (preferences-> settings-User)

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Cobalt.tmTheme",
    "font_size": 13,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "atomic_save": false
}
```

After changing the automic_save value I'm not able to save it.  The error message is: 
Error trying to parse settings: Unexpected trailing characters in ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings:9:2